# How to use SQLAlchemy @compiles decorator for geoalchemy2 types

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I'm trying to create an in-memory SQLite database off of SQLAlchemy ORMs originally designed for a Postgres database. To allow the SQLite engine to convert postgres specific datatypes, I've relied on the SQLAlchemy `@compiles` decorator, which works as intended for types in the `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` namespace.

How can I convert the `geoalchemy2.Raster` data type to a engine-agnostic data type (it could be a `sqlalchemy.BLOB` type for all I care. The important thing is that I can create tables that are similar, they don't need to be exact)?

This example code converts the `DOUBLE_PRECISION` type as intended, but I'm at a loss for how to modify the `geoalchemy2.Raster` data type which is a `UserDefinedType`. I'd like to be able to write a similar method to `compile_DOUBLE_PRECISION()` that changes `Raster` into a `BLOB` type.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DOUBLE_PRECISION
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base import SQLiteTypeCompiler
from geoalchemy2 import Raster

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_model"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    double_precision = Column(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
    raster = Column(Raster)

# The following @compiles works as intended
@compiles(DOUBLE_PRECISION, 'sqlite')
def compile_DOUBLE_PRECISION(element, compiler: SQLiteTypeCompiler, **kw):
    """ Handles postgres DOUBLE_PRECISION datatype as REAL in sqlite. """
    return compiler.visit_real(element, **kw)

def test_throws_error_due_to_raster_data_type():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with postgresql but maybe something like this could work

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from geoalchemy2 import Raster

Base = declarative_base()


def raster_if_postgresql_else_blob():
    return sa.BLOB().with_variant(Raster, "postgresql")


class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_model"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    raster = sa.Column(raster_if_postgresql_else_blob())


lite_engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(lite_engine)
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect. I appreciate that you focused on the larger issue of data variance rather than the @compiles decorator specifically. I adapted your method and greenlit my tests with the following: `def blob_if_sqlite_else_raster(): return Raster().with_variant(BLOB, "sqlite")`